# Use flake8 for Cython with w0rp/ale

Tags: plugin-ale

I'm using `flake8` to check my code with [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) plugin. I found a way to make it work with Python 3, but it seems it does not recognize Cython file (`.pyx`) even if we set as follows.

```
let g:ale_linters = {
\   'cython': ['flake8']
\}
```

I also tried

```
let g:ale_command_wrapper = "source activate py36; %* --filetype=*.py,*.pyx "
```

Is there any way to set it?

Comment: Flake8 isn't supported for PyRex/Cython files. See `:help ale` or the README which lists all the supported linters. You'll have to make a PR to Ale to add it (which is actually pretty easy to do!)

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked on cython, so really don't know if it has a different syntax or something. If the syntax is the same as python, it should be as easy as telling vim to interpret the cython file as a normal python file:

```
:set filetype=python
```

Also, instead of setting the filetype on each file, you can define an autocommand in your vimrc as follows:

```
autocommand BufEnter *.pyx setlocal filetype=python
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, Cython has slightly different syntax from normal Python, and the problem is my syntax highlighter recognizes `*.pyx` (pyrex) files. If I change the filetype, it works for ALE but highlighting is gone.